# Global Constructors with CRTP

Tags: c++, crtp

I'd like to allow a class to inherit from a base CRTP class that causes a global constructor to be created and run before main() begins. The idea is to use this to register a type in some map to be looked up later. It seems that this only works if I've actually instantiated a member of the Derived class and used the Base class.

```
#include <iostream>

class Foo {
 public:
  Foo() { std::cout << "Foo" << std::endl; }
};

template <typename T>
class Bar {
 private:
  static Foo foo_;
};

class Test : public Bar<Test> {
};

int main() {
  return 0;
}
```

class `Test` inherits from `Bar<Test>` which has a static member variable of type `Foo`. Unfortunately, `Foo`'s constructor is not invoked. I'd like to be able to cause a global constructor to be run when a class instantiates a template using CRTP without needing to actually create an instance of that class. I'd be happy with implementation dependent solutions too.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way besides `SomeClass instance` in a translation unit to have a global class instance.

With a template and a static member, you might (or might not) end up with globals in multiple translation unit.

Answer (score 0):

If you declare a class with static fields, it doesn't matter is it template-driven or not - static members would not be instantiated unless you create an instance of such class. And be aware - time of the static members instantiation is quite tricky thing, especially if you have multiple libraries involved.